# Returning the class pointer through function

Tags: c++, class, pointers

How can i return the pointer of the Foo class using its functions. The reason why i ask is because i want to make this code work

```
Class fo
fo.MakeA(34.5777).MakeY(73.8843);
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This is called "Method Chaining," and in my opinion, it is an abomination.  It saves you nothing, makes the code confusing, and gives you many opportunities for bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you need a reference return type;

```
class foo {
public:
  foo& MakeA(float a) {
    // MakeA code logic here...
    return *this;
  } 
  foo& MakeB(float b) {
    // MakeA code logic here...
    return *this;
  } 
}
```

Otherwise, you can just return a copy (`foo` instead of `foo&`).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an indexer for your class.

Make the return-type for (MakeA, MakeY) the same data type as the class (with ref &).

and in the end of every method put

```
return *this;
```